# Speed up adding Items to Forms with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-api

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to add Items to Google Forms with App Script.

My script is taking a long time and I'm wondering if there's anyway to add items more efficiently using an array or something rather than one by one. Here's the code I'm running...

```
function addFormItems() {
  var startTime = new Date(); var form = FormApp.create("Test") form.setIsQuiz(true)
  for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    form.addTextItem().setTitle("Question number " + i).setHelpText("Hint: answer should not be more than a couple of words")
  }
  var endTime = new Date();
  //Get runTime in seconds var runTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
  Logger.log("runtime is: " + runTime)
}
```

Currently it takes quite a long time a minute to a minute and a half (odd thing is every time I execute I get a very different runtime not sure why that happens)  Any thoughts on how to speed this up is much appreciated.

I searched [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) and couldn't find anything about adding multiple items with one call.

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Could you please elaborate further.  I know that linking the sheet will populate the question titles in the first row.  I think that may help with reading the item titles but not sure how I could use that in my case were I need to add items to the form?

Comment: In your situation, how about using Google Forms API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/create)

Comment: So... here I am looking at the comment by @Tanaike and trying to figure out how to _would/could_ I use the Forms API to create questions. And then I found [Creating Quizzes in Google Form using Google Forms API with Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/eebcb2d71eed1aab5decff64287bcc9a). And who do you think is the author of that? Yep, none other than Tanaike.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for this I wasn't aware it could be done that way!  I was looking at the documentation yesterday and spinning my wheels but your code sample which Tedinoz shared is very helpful.  Kudos!!  Will give it a try and post back.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that was useful, I'm glad.